# Android unusual Image Buttons

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I am trying to create a similar main menu design in my android app as you can see in my attachment.

The problem is, the menu buttons are not horizontal, but are oblique and partially overlapping each other.

I tried something like this with ImageButton in RelativeLayout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/menu1"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/simpleImageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/menu2"/>
```

But as the images are not horizontal, I need to store each image as a horizontal with a transparent bottom and upper part, however, that causes, that those parts will be clickable as well, and as they are overlapping, two clickable parts will have collision.

Is any good solution to make this work?

As this menu will be fixed, so no more items will be added, I also thought to make it as one background image and maybe somehow make invisible buttons just for a part of each button, or map somehow each clickable area.

But still, I'd rather go with the ImageButtons way or something easier.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to make custom view for this

Comment: can you pls be more specific? How can I create separate view for each image when they are overlapping, I think the only way would be to use Bitmap and check the clicked coordinates if they are not transparent

Comment: @Darksymphony check this sample app and let men know if it is working https://github.com/bgizdov/android-overlapped-rotated-image-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using FrameLayout with multiple buttons positioned at the desired angle and overlapping each other. Use the attributes `android:rotation` and `android:layout_margin` to control the angle and overlap between buttons.

Here is an example:

Sample app: https://github.com/bgizdov/android-overlapped-rotated-image-buttons

[image: overlapping buttons android]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/menu1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:rotation="15" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/menu2"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:rotation="-10" />

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/simpleImageButton3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/menu3"
      android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
      android:rotation="15" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I can't believe! I was working on it whole day with getting Pixels, Bitmap etc. and just a simple rotation and margin did the trick! Even if the buttons are overlapped, exactly those buttons are clickable that should be. Thank you very much, you saved my life :) Btw. works within RelativeLayout as well.